# Z80 assembly storing a value in a register for longer time

Tags: z80

I have the following part of code:

```
        ld a, 2
INIT:   ld ix, AFIS
        ld c, a
        cp 2
        jp z INIT2
        call SCAN
INIT2:  ld ix, AFIS2
        call SCAN
INIT3: ld ix, AFIS3
       ld c, a
       cp 2
       jp z INIT4
```

The problem is with this code `ld c, a` from `INIT3`. It is like the register "a" has been reset and `cp 2` will be set as false. How I can store a value in a register for longer time?

Comment: I don't see a `ld b, a` in the `INIT3`. Also, does the `SCAN` routine use any of the registers? If so, you could either use an unused register, or wrap the routine in a `push`...`pop`.

Comment: sorry, i mean `ld c, a`. The scan is used for the ix register. I will try with push and pop, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure SCAN can be changing *anything* it likes.

If you are not in control of SCAN and SCAN does not have a documented list of registers that it changes then you will need to keep the registers that are important for you safe.

Using the stack:

```
        ld a,2
INIT:   
        ld ix,AFIS
        ld c,a
        cp 2
        push af     ; store value of register pair af on stack
        jp z,INIT2

        call SCAN

INIT2:  ld ix,AFIS2
        call SCAN

INIT3:  ld ix,AFIS3
        pop af      ; get value of register pair af from stack - f = flags 
                    ; since comparison was identical, no need to recompare
        jp z,INIT4
```

Using a memory location as a variable store:

```
        ld a,2
INIT:   
        ld (var),a    ; store it
        ld ix,AFIS        
        ld c,a
        cp 2
        jp z,INIT2

        call SCAN

INIT2:  ld ix,AFIS2        
        call SCAN

INIT3:  ld ix,AFIS3

        ld a,(var)    ; get it assuming scan does not need it
        ld c,a
        cp 2
        jp z,INIT4

...

var:    defb 0
```